# save sequence of frame as BMP not PNG

Tags: c#, image, video, ffmpeg, bmp

I extract 100 frames from video file and i save each frame as (.bmp) but i found that each frame format is PNG not BMP , how can I save sequence of frame (format as BMP not PNG as show in picture)in C# ?

```
string name;            
for ( int i = 0; i < 100; i++ )
{
    Bitmap videoFrame = video.ReadVideoFrame( );  
    name = (i).ToString().PadLeft(5, '0');
    videoFrame.Save(@"D:\frames\" + name  + ".bmp");
    videoFrame.Dispose( );
}

video.Close( );
MessageBox.Show(" Complete Convert video to sequence of image","Convert");
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.imageformat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to define the format.

Use this:

```
videoFrame.Save(@"D:\frames\" + name  + ".bmp", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

instead of:

```
videoFrame.Save(@"D:\frames\" + name  + ".bmp");
```

Comment: @user2922938 if it helped you. You can choose it as answer so other people won't need to read it again to answer you